# How to delete a line of a data frame in python using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete the line that is in the loop.

I tried data.drop(), but it doesn't work

```
    for i,  receb in enumerate(data['recebimento']):
    
    if ordem == data.iloc[i, data.columns.get_loc('ordem')]:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*::content"]').send_keys(str(imei))
        print(imei)
        data.drop(i)
```

| codigo_produto | recebimento | orden | imei |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12d | 123 | 4513512 | ijam153 |
| 6412 | 171 | 45454 | 56656a |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be difficult to delete items from a collection you are also iterating. Rows get shifted by 1 and your index, still using the original postion and size of the collection, indexes the wrong row and eventually overflows. Also, iterating rows in pandas is relatively expensive. Since pandas is geared towards broadcasting an operation across the entire array, there is usually a better way to do it.

Here you can select the rows you want, perform operations and then drop the lot of them. I can't tell from your example what data you want to use from the dataframe, so this is just an estimate of the final code,

```
selected_imei = data[data["ordem"] == ordem]["imei"]
for imei in selected_imei:
    print("do stuff with", imei)
data.drop(selected_imei.index)
```

Comment: It's kind of working but it looks like it's duplicating the lines when inserting the lines

Comment: In this example, I selected rows where ordem is a certain value so you always get a single value. I couldn't figure out what your for loop was supposed to do because it doesn't use any of the enumerated values, so all I did was select the "ordem" column and print its values. (which was just the single searched value of course - it made for a boring example).

Comment: Get it. Actually, I need to filter the same values in the column 'ordem' and insert the values from the column 'imei'.

Comment: @TayaneVarela - I changed to select the "imei" column. Hopefully that makes more sense!

Answer (score 0):

Pandas drop method is not defaulted to perform the operation in place, but it returns a resulting dataframe; to change this, use the `inplace` flag. It is also good idea to specify the axis you're dropping; it defaults to 0 (Rows), but makes your code cleaner. Finally, your drop should look something like this:

`data.drop(i, axis=0, inplace=True)`

Comment: So what should I use?

Comment: Try `data.drop(i, axis=0, inplace=True)`

Comment: It doesn't work. ''Exception has occurred: KeyError
'[0] not found in axis''

Comment: Can you show a sample of your dataframe? It seems like the index is not auto-generated, so you'd need to drop by your current index. You can also call `data.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)` in case you don't really need a different index, but that would need to be done before the loop

Comment: SURE. Actually, its necessary